# xpath find element based on the value of other element

Tags: xpath

Honestly, i don't even know how to properly name the topic, cause it's complicated xpath task.

this is html i have:

```
<tr>
    <td class="CY">
        <div class="rc">Name Dynamic&lt;email1990@mail.com&gt;</div>
    </td>
    <td class="qy CY"> </td>
    <td class="qy CY"><span id=":7b0" class="sA" tabindex="0" role="link">изменить</span></td>
    <td class="qw CY"></td>
</tr>
```

The only fixed things here is the  structure and the email `email1990@mail.com`.

**Question:** How to get this element `<span id=":7b0" class="sA" tabindex="0" role="link">изменить</span>` based on `email1990@mail.com` by XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `td` with div containing the email and get `span` from the 2nd td after

```
//td[contains(div, "email1990@mail.com")]//following-sibling::td[2]/span
```